# User tree - get all users of certain stages

Tags: php, symfony, recursion

I have got a problem with the following case:

Im aquiring by a recursive function a tree of users with child users. I will use it for a affiliate system.

```
function getChildUsersRecursive($user, $users=array()) {
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneById($user->getId());
    $childUsers = $user->getChildUsers();

    foreach ($childUsers as $childUser) {

        if (!$childUser->getChildUsers()->isEmpty()) {
            $users[$childUser->getId()] = $this->getChildUsersRecursive($childUser, $users);
        } else {
            $users[$childUser->getId()] = array();
        }
    }

    return $users;
}
```

This works fine. The result is an array like this:

```
array:3 [
  2 => array:1 [
    6 => array:1 [
      7 => array:1 [
        8 => []
      ]
    ]
  ]
  3 => []
  4 => []
]
```

Now I want to create a function getUsersByStage($user, $stage) to get all users of a certain stage for the given user.

Imagine user 3 and user 4 have got also one child user. By calling getUsersByStage($user, 0) I want to get all entries of the first dimension, in this example user 2, 3 and 4.
By calling getUsersByStage($user, 1) I want to have all these users that are one stage deeper, so the direct child users of user 2, 3 and 4.

I hope you understand what I mean. I think its simple but I am unable to see the wood for the trees.

Thank you in advance and wish you a merry christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a BFS walk in this tree and output users that are at given depth. Below example assumes you already have users array for given user.

```
$a = [ 2 => [ 6=> [ 7=> [8=>[]]] ], 3 => [], 4 => [] ];


function getUsersByStage($users, $stage)
{
    $usersFound = [];
    $q = new \SplQueue();
    /* enqueue current array, level, user (key value) */
    $q->enqueue([$users, -1, -1]);
    while (!$q->isEmpty()) {
       $elem = $q->dequeue();
       $currentUserArray = $elem[0];
       $currentLevel = $elem[1];
       if ($currentLevel > $stage) break;
       $currentUser = $elem[2];
       if ($currentLevel == $stage) $usersFound[] = $currentUser;
       /* enqueue all children */
       foreach ($currentUserArray as $user=>$subArray) {
          $q->enqueue([$subArray, $currentLevel+1, $user]);
       }
    }
    return $usersFound;
}
print_r(getUsersByStage($a, 0)); /* [2, 3, 4] */
print_r(getUsersByStage($a, 1)); /* [6] */
print_r(getUsersByStage($a, 2)); /* [7] */
print_r(getUsersByStage($a, 3)); /* [8] */
print_r(getUsersByStage($a, 4)); /* [] */
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast and pretty solution, it works like a charm! :)